# VSCODE how to debug python in conda environment in docker container in remote server

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, conda, remote-server

I start by enabling the docker container in the remote server, then I connect VSCODE to that server via SSH, and finally I attach VSCODE to the docker (docker extension installed).
I have selected the interpreter in the conda environment by editing a ./.vscode/launch.json file
When I start the python program debug the packages available in the conda environment are not visible to the python program.
What am I doing wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to select the Interpreter inside VSCode.
First open up the Command Palette `Ctrl+Shift+P`, then type `Python: Select Interpreter` then select the environment you want to use.

Comment: Right answer indeed!